# Power Apps SharePoint form setting date/time field to blank

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, powerapps

I have a form that sits on top of a O365 SharePoint site list with a simple submit button to set the status and the submit date like this:

```
Patch('LTRequest', ThisItem,{
   SubmitDate: Now(),Status:Text("Pending Approval")});
Back();
```

What I want to do is create a reset button to change the status and set the date to blank or nothing. But no matter what I try the date is not affected and no error is thrown. Here's what the reset button looks like:

```
Patch('LTRequest', ThisItem,{
   SubmitDate: DateValue(Blank()),Status: "Draft", ApprovalDate: Blank()});
Back();
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

From my own experience earlier this year, and my investigation, you can't clear a datetime field in SharePoint from PowerApps..

I know - crazy!  It may be fixed now but it doesn't like it is..

There's a workaround [here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Update-blank-Null-value-to-fields-Date-User-Choice-field-etc-in/m-p/178754#M59198)

"I ended up adding a second column in sharepoint
Date/time and text
I set text to be the date column that shows in sharepoint.  Date/time column is hidden.
I set text field to = date or blank"

Answer (score 0):

You can enable an experimental feature to get around that: **Formula-level error management**

However, you might introduce more errors/promblems to the app by turning that feature on.

[image: Formula-level error management]

Comment: Does that allow a date/time field to be reset to blank? I've read that all data types should respond to the ```IsBlank()``` function so I assumed the ```Blank()``` function should also be allowed. By the way, I am not seeing any error message so I'm not entire sure what this feature will gain me.

Comment: You can read more about it on this page https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/new-feature-error-handling-and-writing-null-values-to-databases/. It basically states that to write null back to some data sources, you need to turn that feature on so power apps can differentiate null and error. In you case, you write {SubmitDate: Blank(),...}

Answer (score 0):

I'd remove the `Back()` statement during debugging. You might *actually* be receiving an error but because you're navigating away from the screen right away, you may be missing it.

That being said, remove the `DateValue` from around `Blank()` and try that.

```
Patch(
    'LTRequest', 
    ThisItem,
        {
            SubmitDate: Blank(),
            Status: "Draft", 
            ApprovalDate: Blank()
        }
)
```

If that doesn't work, I'd try an [`Update()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-update-updateif#update-function) function:

```
Update(
    'LTRequest', 
    ThisItem,
        {
            SubmitDate: Blank(),
            Status: "Draft", 
            ApprovalDate: Blank()
        }
)
```